# How can I study the following sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let we have the following sequences 
$x_n=1/1^2 + 1/2^2 + ....1/n^2$ Prove that for any $n$ $x_n <= 2-1/n  $ how can I calculate its limit ?

$y_n= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+..........+\frac{1}{\  \sqrt{n^2+n}}$ find the limit of the sequence $y_n$

Let $z_0=3$ and $ z_{n+1}=\frac{2}{z_n +1} $ and $t_n=\frac{z_n-1}{z_n+2}$ prove that $t_n$ is a geometric sequence find its general form

Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first inequality we can use that $$\frac{1}{i^2}\le \frac{1}{i(i-1)}$$ for $$i>1$$

---

For the second limit, one can see that

$$\int_1^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+x}}\ dx\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\le\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\int_1^n\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+x}}\ dx$$

Evaluating these, we have

$$2(\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-\sqrt{n^2+1})\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\le\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+2(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1})$$

As $n\to\infty$, we have, by squeeze theorem with a touch of binomial expanding,

$$y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}=1$$

Comment: :-P For those who still don't see, try partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: You don't mind if I edit your answer to include $y_n$'s limit?

Comment: Can you explain it more ?